# I am getting so much verbose in output window. Apache Netbeans 12

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting so much lines when I run my code before the actual compiled code.

[image: Check it out here. I am trying to print out Hello World word]

I use Apache Netbeans 12. I am coding Java (JDK 14).
I looked it up but all the tutorials I came through don't have these extra lines.

This is what I got. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal output from Ant. The only option you have to influence that, is to run Ant with the `-q` option.

This can be done using "Tools -> Options -> Java -> Ant"

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's almost resolved it, it eliminated a lot of lines, I still have this line, any idea? ant -q -f C:\\Users\\$$$$$\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run